# Powerbi conditional column - conditions from two other tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a model that contains 3 tables, Account, Document, and Detail. Account and Document are related to Detail like so:
[image]

My goal is to have a table like below that shows Document Type, Account, Amount, and Type. I need to create a new conditional column to the Detail table that populates Type, but if the Document Type = "Memo" then I want the new conditional column to populate blank.
[image]